# jQuery find id, that's inside data-target attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the id, that's inside a data target.

For structure, i mean like this

```
PARENT (DATA TARGET)
  |
  V
CHILD (ID)
```

Hope that makes a more clear vision

I've tried the following code here.:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("a.print").click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-target").find("#edit_cookie"); // Look for the id inside data-target
    alert($(id));
  });
});
```

But all it gives is this

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).find is not a function

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/4pa3hqgt/2/

What can i do here?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to find the parent and then choose its child and read ID from there.

First you select the parent. Then access children and use some selector to get the one you want and there you get the id attribute. So it should look something like this:

edit to work with your html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.print').on("click", function () {
    var id = $('div[data-target="customized"]>div').attr('id'); 
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

working example in comments bellow

Comment: `alert($(id));` would always produce `"[object Object]"`

Comment: you are right, I concentrated just on the first part of the code :-) to print out the value its just alert(id);

Comment: Hey, thanks! :-) I've added an JSFiddle to the post :-)

Comment: I used plnkr to edit it and there it is working. https://plnkr.co/edit/xqnoV8f12TAlY59RM678?p=preview